# making a setup file to program that is using c# and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

i made a program in c# with mysql workbench and i made the connection using this code :

```
  string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
```

so i don't have a database file its just a server and i need to make a setup file that includes the database and the program file , i searched the net but i couldn't find anything relative to what i want  , there was tutorial  about making a setup with a .mdb database file but i dont have that and i dont know how to make one

any help would be appreciated

Comment: To clarify: You would like your "setup file" (installer?) to install a local instance of MySQL to host your application's database? Take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want a local database. I'd recommend you using SQLite which is a simple, lightweight file based database.

Here's the link [SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

Comment: MySQL Workbench is only a unified visual tool for the database and not the database itself. MySql has to be installed. It's not as light as SQLite is.